# Using CSS to restrict scrollbars to nested divs SOLVED

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am writing a userscript to add hotkeys to a website.  I am new to web programming, so consider me a novice when it comes to HTML/JS/CSS (this is my learning project).  I primarily use Firefox on Linux for this.  Because this is all about hotkeys, I'm not too worried about solving this for mobile, but I am happy to take solutions that work there, too.

I am currently trying to improve the pop-up help view.  The help is a `dialog` element with some simple header like information like *Click on the tabs* and *Hit ESC to close*. And a tab-view with simple content.  One tab panel is a table listing keystrokes, a second is just some simple documentation, and a third is just a big `textarea` element that I will populate with error messages that the user can copy and paste into a bug report.

The example has a few issues I'd like to address, but this question is about scrolling.

```js
// This just populates the HTML skeleton with dummy data.  Then shows the dialog.
let i = 0;
let j = 0
let s = '<table><tbody>';
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  s += `<tr><th></th><th>Section ${i}</th></tr>`;
  for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    s += `<tr><td>hint-${i}-${j}</td><td>Somewhat wordy description about this bit of information that tends to ramble on and on.</td></td>`;
  }
}
s += '</tbody></table>';
t = '';
for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  t += `<p>This is some rambling text about subject ${i}.  It too can be wordy.</p>`;
}
u = '<div class="yaf">';
u += '<p>Before text</p>';
u += '<textarea placeholder="Nothing interesting here">';
u += 'I have to put something interesting here.\n\n';
u += document.querySelector('#d').outerHTML;
u += '\n---\n';
u += '</textarea>';
u += '<p>After text.</p>';
u += '</div>';
document.querySelector('div[data-name="Table"]').innerHTML = s;
document.querySelector('div[data-name="Documentation"]').innerHTML = t;
document.querySelector('div[data-name="TextArea"]').innerHTML = u;
const b = document.querySelector('#b');
b.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('#d').showModal();
});
```

```css
dialog:modal {
  height: 90%;
  width: 70%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

p {
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

.instructions {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.instructions>span {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

nav label {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.panel {
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

#this-tab>input[data-name="Table"]:checked~nav>[data-name="Table"],
#this-tab>input[data-name="Documentation"]:checked~nav>[data-name="Documentation"],
#this-tab>input[data-name="TextArea"]:checked~nav>[data-name="TextArea"] {
  color: green;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}

#this-tab>input[data-name="Table"]:checked~div[data-name="Table"],
#this-tab>input[data-name="Documentation"]:checked~div[data-name="Documentation"],
#this-tab>input[data-name="TextArea"]:checked~div[data-name="TextArea"] {
  display: block;
}

/* yet another flex */
.yaf {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<button id="b">Open dialog</button>

<dialog id="d">
  <div><b>Application title</b> - v1.2.3</div>
  <div class="instructions">
    <span class="left">Click on the tabs.</span>
    <span class="right">Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close.</span>
  </div>
  <div id="this-tab" class="container">
    <input id="tab-1" data-name="Table" name="tabber" type="radio" checked>
    <input id="tab-2" data-name="Documentation" name="tabber" type="radio">
    <input id="tab-3" data-name="TextArea" name="tabber" type="radio">
    <nav>
      <label for="tab-1" data-name="Table">[Table]</label>
      <label for="tab-2" data-name="Documentation">[Documentation]</label>
      <label for="tab-3" data-name="TextArea">[TextArea]</label>
    </nav>
    <div class="panel" data-name="Table"></div>
    <div class="panel" data-name="Documentation"></div>
    <div class="panel" data-name="TextArea"></div>
    <p>Container footer.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Dialog footer.</p>
</dialog>
```

Since there is header like information in both the simple text at the top and the tab headers, I'd like to restrict scrolling to the content in the tab panels themselves (that is, the table, documentation or textarea); keeping the headers in view.

I have tried a number of different combinations of CSS properties and values to limit scrollbars only showing up on the panels themselves.  Those that I've tried include `box-sizing`, `overflow`, `height`, `position`, `overflow`, `display`, `bottom`, `top`, and likely a few others.  For each of those, I've tried nearly every possible value of keywords, lengths and percents.  And those would be applied to every nested `div` and `dialog`.

I think a couple of (probably equivalent) combinations resulted in scrollbars on both the dialog itself and a nested panel.  Which seemed close, but not quite what I want.

The example is purposefully stripped down to provide a starting point.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.  (Actually, if anyone has any quick and easy pointers to make the textarea fill the entire third panel, that would be cool, otherwise I'll eventually ask a followup question about that.)

**Update 2023-09-06**  I have updated the example code with my latest experiments.  It is a variation of what @shabaz-lakhani did: I put the `overflow-y: auto` on the `.panels` container, rather than each `.panel` itself.

The inline *Run code snippet* view is a little short, and for some reason the example does not show the scrollbar.  The panels will scroll if you click on them just right.  But popping out to *Full page* works much better.

I am really not keen on the whole `height: calc(100% - <fudge-factor>);` approach.  I'd rather just know how to pin to bottom of the tab container/panels/panel/whatever to the padding of the dialog.

Unrelated, I changed the tab headers from a `div` to a `nav` (not that I think it matters much), and switch from `<span style="float: right">` to using a flexbox with `flex-grow: 1`.  My external experiments indicates this works better in general when the page is narrowed.

This moving the `label`s away from the `input`s also meant that I had to change the CSS to highlight the current label from adjacent sibling (`+`) to general sibling (`~`).

I also switched from using `nth-of-type` approach to using `[data-name="foo"]`.  I have to know how many `nth-of-type` selectors to put into place anyway, and since all of the content is built on the fly using JS anyway, it was no harder to do that than using a counter.

Anyway, close to what I want.  It functions mostly like what I want.  I would just prefer to have something more principled than how that `calc()`.

**Update 2023-09-06 #2**  The example now works as I want, with no `calc()`.  I don't quite understand the magical use of `height: 0`.

I'm going to write up a separate answer with details as the question itself has gotten quite long.

**Update 2023-09-06 #3**  Found a bug.  If we set `display: flex` in the dialog's style, then the dialog will always show.  Need to use the `:modal` pseudo-class as an additional constraint.

Demo updated to include a button to show the dialog on demand.

**Update 2023-09-06 #4**  Found a weakness in the approach I was using.  By having the `div.panels` wrapper, it resulted in the scrollbar on that div.  Which seemed like a good idea at the time.

However, it means the scroll position stays the same as one goes to other tabs, which I found confusing.

Eliminating that wrapper and placing the scrollbar directly on `div.panel`, each tab gets its own state.

And, since I was in here doing another edit anyway, went ahead and applied the `overflow-y: scroll; height: 0;` change I mentioned in the answer.

Interestingly, the CSS I'd previously applied to the `textarea` element suddenly started working, and did not play well with always having the panel scrollbar turned on.  So I backed that out for now (it is still a challenge, but not the one I was looking to solve in this particular post).

Also tweaked the `p` CSS to demo works inline now.  Though I still think the full page version looks better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out without needing to use `calc()`.  It seems to act reasonably as I change the size of the browser window.

I ended up using nested flexboxes.

First, I had to make the `dialog` a columnar flexbox.

The `.container` class is set to `flex-grow: 1` for that flexbox, but itself is also a columnar flexbox.

One bit that took me a long time to figure out is getting the panel content to stay within the space allocated for the panel.  It turns out that flex items (the panel in this case) default to not be smaller than their content.  This can be solved by adding any one of these three settings to the container styling: `height: 0`, `min-height: 0`, `overflow-y: hidden`.  (Of course, using `flex-direction: row`, switch those to `width` and `-x` as appropriate.)  As best as I can tell, the height variants also affect the default `flex-basis`, but I have not experimented with that yet.

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/3799957) for more details.

More importantly, this approach works in my real app!

The only thing I dislike there is that as I move between tabs, some have scrollbars and some do not, so the text in the panels have an inconsistent width.  I might change the `overflow-y: auto` to `overflow-y: scroll; height: 100%` to make the scrollbar always visible (and always the same height).

I was going to put a rough outline here, but looking back, I think the current example in the original question is fairly good.

It is pure CSS.  The JS is only used to build the content (since I am using a userscript).  The selectors to tie the `input` elements to the associated `label` and `div` elements are a little chatty, but at least consistent between the two.  Only the panels get scrollbars, headers and footers stayed put (as I was writing this, I updated the demo to include footers).  And each panel can have completely different types of content.

In my real world example, I happen to use a `section` element for the container rather than a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
dialog {
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 90%;
} 
.tabber input:nth-of-type(1):checked~.panels>.panel:nth-of-type(1),
.tabber input:nth-of-type(2):checked~.panels>.panel:nth-of-type(2),
.tabber input:nth-of-type(3):checked~.panels>.panel:nth-of-type(3) {
display: block;
max-height: calc(100% - 2em); /* Adjust the height as needed */
overflow-y: auto;
}
.panel {
display: none;
}
textarea {
resize: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: none;
}
dialog > div {
padding: 0.5em;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>
<dialog id="d">
<div>
<span>Click on the tabs.</span>
<span style="float: right">Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to close.</span>
</div>
<div class="tabber">
<input id="tab-1" name="tabber" type="radio" checked>
<label for="tab-1">[Table]</label>
<input id="tab-2" name="tabber" type="radio">
<label for="tab-2">[Documentation]</label>
<input id="tab-3" name="tabber" type="radio">
<label for="tab-3">[TextArea]</label>
<div class="panels">
  <div id="panel-1" class="panel"></div>
  <div id="panel-2" class="panel"></div>
  <div id="panel-3" class="panel">
    <textarea placeholder="Nothing interesting here"></textarea>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</dialog>
<script>
document.querySelector('#d').showModal();
</script>
```

Here's a modified version of your code that achieves these goals:

- Added max-height and overflow-y properties to the panel containers to
  limit their height and enable scrolling when the content overflows.
- Adjusted the height calculation for the panels to account for the
  header height (approximately 2em).
- Added width: 100%; and height:100%; to the textarea to make it fill
  the entire third panel.
- Styled the header area of the dialog with background color and border
  to differentiate it from the panels. Please note that you may need to
  fine-tune the max-height value and other styles to achieve the exact
  layout you're aiming for.
- Additionally, ensure that your actual    content populates the panels
  as needed.

Comment: I updated my example with your input.  Unfortunately, the scrollbars still attach themselves to the dialog instead of the panels.  [I see I can't add images to these comments, so I'll add some to the post.]